# Passing through a subsequence of bash arguments to a function

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass all arguments after `--` through to a function.

Here is an example invocation of the script.

```
$ ./myscript.sh exec -- run "Hello  World"
Arg 1 run
Arg 2 Hello  World
```

How can I modify the `myscript.sh` (below) for the desired output?

```
#! /bin/bash

f () {
  echo Arg 1 "$1"
  echo Arg 2 "$2"
}

ARGS=
CHILD_ARGS=

# Look to see if we want to pass args through to a script
for ((ARGS_POS=1 ; ARGS_POS <= $# ; ARGS_POS++)); do
  if [[ "--" == ${!ARGS_POS} ]]; then
    ((ARGS_POS++))

    CHILD_ARGS=${@:$ARGS_POS}
    ARGS=${@:1:$((ARGS_POS-2))}
    break
  fi
done

# Do something $ARGS

# Run the child
f $CHILD_ARGS
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to remove all positional parameters up til and including `--`:

```
% cat myscript.bash
#!/bin/bash
while [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$1" != "--" ]; do :
  shift
done
shift
printf "<%s>\n" "$@"
```

Testing:

```
% ./myscript.bash exec -- run 'hello world'
<run>
<hello world>
% ./myscript.bash 1 2 3
<>
% ./myscript.bash 'hello world' -- 'john doe'
<john doe>
```

This can also be done with any array both is a little more fiddly:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=("$@")
i=0
while [ "${#arr[@]}" -gt 0 ] && [ "${arr[$i]}" != "--" ]; do :
  unset arr[$i]
  ((i+=1))
done
unset arr[$i]
printf "<%s>\n" "${arr[@]}"
printf -- "--------\n"
printf "<%s>\n" "$@"
```

Test:

```
./myscript.bash john doe -- 'hello world' a b
<hello world>
<a>
<b>
--------
<john>
<doe>
<-->
<hello world>
<a>
<b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script to achieve the requirement,

```
    #! /bin/bash

    f () {
      echo Arg 1 "$1"
      echo Arg 2 "$2 $3"
    }

    ARGS=
    CHILD_ARGS=

    # Look to see if we want to pass args through to a script
    for ((ARGS_POS=1 ; ARGS_POS <= $# ; ARGS_POS++)); do
      if [[ "--" == ${!ARGS_POS} ]]; then
        CHILD_ARGS=${@:$ARGS_POS+1}
        ARGS=${@:1:$((ARGS_POS-2))}
        break
      fi
    done

    # Do something $ARGS

    # Run the child
    f $CHILD_ARGS
```

In the above script, values are passing using only a single variable called  "$CHILD_ARGS". Because of this, in function, function argument will divide w.r.t space.

Comment: Does this preserve the two spaces between "Hello" and "World"?

Comment: No, if you want space, then you should assign $2 and $3 values to a variable and then print it. like var="$2 $3"; echo "$var"

Comment: andlrc's answer has the benefit that I don't have to do that and it will preserve the spaces. I just wanted to give you the same opportunity he had. Thanks for your help again!